# Matter Modelers: Let's all wear our hats!

Tags: discussion, participation, voting, winter-bash

I pointed out last year in this question: [HATS !!!!! GET SPECIAL HATS ON 21 DEC, 25 DEC, AND 1 JAN!](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/227/5), that activity on SE sites often drops during late December / early January, and a loss of momentum on a new site can be detrimental.

[Winter Bash](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/mattermodeling.stackexchange.com) is a fun way to keep people engaged.

By wearing our hats and making them as big as possible, we can raise awareness about Winter Bash for all the newer SE users who may not be familiar with it and therefore might regrettably miss out on the opportunity for fun!

Here's some of my favorite hats I've seen worn on MMSE so far (which ended up being from 100% of the users on [this page](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month) with pictures of themselves wearing something from Winter Bash):

[image] [image] [image] [image]

## Let's all wear our hats as big as possible to raise awareness about Winter Bash!

You can also [show off your hat network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/373051/391772) and/or support other matter modelers there.

Thank you to all users who have earned at least three hats so far: keep it up!

[image]